# Best practices for exception handling and safe coding

Tags: c#, exception

Say you were calling a method similar to the following, which you know is only ever going to throw one of 2 exceptions:

```
public static void ExceptionDemo(string input)
{
    if (input == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("input");

    if (input.Contains(","))
        throw new ArgumentException("input cannot contain the comma character");

    // ...
    // ... Some really impressive code here
    // ...
}
```

A real life example of a method which does this is [Membership.GetUser (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40w5063z.aspx)

Which of the following would you use to call the method and handle the exceptions:

**Method 1 (check the input param first first)**

```
public static void Example1(string input)
{
    // validate the input first and make sure that the exceptions could never occur
    // no [try/catch] required
    if (input != null && !input.Contains(","))
    {
        ExceptionDemo(input);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("input cannot be null or contain the comma character");
    }
}
```

**Method 2 (wrap the call in a try / catch)**

```
public static void Example2(string input)
{
    // try catch block with no validation of the input
    try
    {
        ExceptionDemo(input);
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("input cannot be null");
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("input cannot contain the comma character");
    }
}
```

I've had both methods taught over the years and wondered what the general best practise was for this scenario.

**Update**
*Several posters were focusing on the method throwing the exceptions and not the way these exceptions were being handled, so I've provided an example of a .Net Framework method which behaves in the same way ([Membership.GetUser (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40w5063z.aspx))
So, to clarify my question, if you we're calling `Membership.GetUser(input)` how would you handle the possible exceptions, Method 1, 2 or something else?*

Thanks

Comment: Method1 of course exceptions are expensive and in this case you can avoid them with a simple check.

Comment: Exceptions should not happen for intended program behavior, only for exceptional (that's why they are called Exceptions) situations which are not forseen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends, but generally, neither method presented is good. As has been said, in the first case, you are duplicating code. In the second, you are catching the exception without actually doing anything about it - not even rethrowing, just swallowing it. If you want just to log it or display some message, normally you should implement a global handler/logger using [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) and do it there; this way, you don't have to pollute your code with unnecessary try/catch blocks.

The real question here is whether or not input being null or containing ',' is really an exceptional behavior in your specific case - e.g. if this is some GUI-entered string, then this should normally not result in an exception throw (end-user mistakes should be expected) and should be handled appropriately (e.g. with a warning to re-entry the input). In such case, using `if` statements to validate the input is the proper way. However, if input being null or containing ',' is an actual exceptional behavior (say, an API problem which indicates something's broken or missing) then throwing exception is ok. In this case, you can simply call `ExceptionDemo(input)` without try/catch. If you want to actually do something about the exception (e.g. change the input in some way), then use try/catch.

Comment: I think this is the explanation which makes the most sense to me.  I've updated the question with an example of a Framework method which throws the exceptions mentioned in my example, does this alter your opinion at all?

Comment: Sorry for a late response. It would depend on the context in which `GetUser()` is called - e.g. is user entering the username into a textbox? In this case, I (note that some people might disagree) would validate the input using the first method (`if`) before `GetUser()` invocation, because typos are expected. However, say the username is a string retrieved from the database and is supposed to be valid already - in this case, I would use `try/catch`, because a string containing , or being null would indicate some database operation problem, i.e. exceptional behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Callers should not assume anything about code they're calling.

Your first example is bad, because you're duplicating code: the caller performs **almost** (`string.INOE()` vs `string == null`) the same check as the callee (until either of them changes).

The second example is extremely bad as it ignores the thrown exceptions and gives its own interpretation to them.

As usual: it depends. If you have a properly layered application where the method calls are in your UI layer, you **do** want to just catch the exception the method throws: you'll want to display those errors to the user.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how many times ExceptionDemo is called and who it is exposed to. If it was used extensively, you wouldn't want to check the conditions before calling ExceptionDemo, when you know (and document) that ExceptionDemo does the checks anyway.

Given the return type is void, what about changing ExceptionDemo to have no effect if the input is wrong?

(Did you notice that you are stricter in Method 1 - the empty string is not a valid input, but in Method 2 it is)

Comment: "Did you notice that you are stricter in Method 1" --> Well spotted, an oversight on my part.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend standard and generic structure as below :

```
public static void Operation(object input)
{
    try
    {
        ValidateInput(input);
        //Do Operation
    }
    catch (MySpecificException subSubExceptionType) //Catch most specific exceptions
    {

        //Log or process exception
        throw;
    }
    catch (MySpecificException subExceptionType) //Catch specific exception
    {
        //Log or process exception
    }
    catch (Exception exceptionType) //Catch most generic exception
    {

        //Log or process exception
    }
    finally
    {
        //Release the resources
    }
}

private static void ValidateInput(object input)
{
    if(input == null)
        throw new NoNullAllowedException();
    //Check if properties of input are as expected. If not as expected then throw specific exception with specific message
}
```